# Execute JavaScript after new page load

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the current page url with a new url then execute some javascript code once the new url has finished loading. Right now this is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload = "myFunction()">

<h1>My Title</h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   window.open("http://www.example.com", "_self");   
   myFunction1();
}

function myFunction1() {
   alert(location.href);
   My Code
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open my html file the alert(location.href) executes first then the window.open executes. I want this to be reversed where the window.open executes first, then once the new url is finished loading my second function executes.

Also which way is better to change the url

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
window.open("http://www.example.com", "_self");
```

Comment: You can attach your function to the onload event of the window you're opening: window.onload

Comment: Maybe you can explain *why* you want to do this, and we can find alternative solutions.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm trying to implement a form autofill where I change the url to a page that has forms and use javascript to fill out the forms

Comment: If the other page is from a different domain than where your JS code is from you can't do that anyway, since you are not allowed to access the DOM of the other page.

Comment: @RafaelDiaz How would I attach my second function to the onload of the new window?

Comment: @FelixKling How does google autofill for forms work? That is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you talking about Google Chrome? The browser can of course access any page. It's more privileged. Maybe you want to write a browser extension instead.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes I was referring to Google Chrome. Thank you for your suggestion about writing an extension instead.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to execute the JavaScript on the newly opened page. It's like this because if you could do this hackers could make JavaScript injections.

Comment: How can i attach my second function to the newly opened page

Comment: @user3803788 Yes. You would have to do `window.onload` on your second page.

Comment: how do I refer to the onload of the second page? Would this work?


    window.open("www.example.com");
    window.onload = myFunction1();

Comment: @user3803788 In order to do this you have to own the second page and you must modify the JavaScript executed on the second page. No, that wouldn't work. That would do nothing because that is referring to loading the page you're on which is already loaded.

Answer (score -1):

This is impossible. Imagine the security implications of this:

```
window.open("http://some-bank-with-lots-of-money.com", "_self");
var trans = createTransaction();
trans.sendMoney({
    amount: 10000,
    to: "evilHackerGuy"
});
trans.execute();
```

If you are the owner of the page and you want to execute specific code depending on how the user got to the page, try [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer). You could also check this server-side; for example, with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in PHP.